# Uber - Ride Request multiple stops/destinations

Tags: uber-api

According to [Uber's API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-post) docs to create a Ride Request I need to specify at minimum:

- Start Location
- End Location
- Fare ID

I would like to add intermeidary locations between Start and End Location. Is it possible to add it programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to add multiple locations. The only way would be to set the end location and then use the PATCH /requests/current endpoint to update the destinations during the trip.

Comment: Does it need to be triggered by user or can it be automated?

Comment: It can be automated via the api. If you are using an upfront fare and change the destination that fare will no longer be valid.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, but currently Uber APIs are to use only in the 3rd party applications? There is no way to display 3rd party content inside the Uber's native app ?

Comment: Correct. With Trip Experiences you can reach people
while they ride by creating a custom experience in a third-party app with the context of Uber.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: Is this information still valid? I don't see an option of requesting a ride with multiple stops in the api.